# Android Vibrations not working on version 10 and above

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications, android-vibration

I am using ZBarScannerView to scan the barcode after successfully scanning i want to use vibrations.So i use below code and also mention in manifiest file.But it not works

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

 Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
        } else {
            //deprecated in API 26
            v.vibrate(500);
        }
```

This is the code where i am applying vibrator

```
 private void submitQRcode(String houseid) {

    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
    } else {
        //deprecated in API 26
        v.vibrate(500);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "submitQRcode: " + houseid);
    if (houseid.substring(0, 2).matches("^[HhPp]+$"))
        validateTypeOfCollection(houseid);
    else if (houseid.substring(0, 2).matches("^[GgPp]+$"))
        startSubmitQRAsyncTask(houseid, -1, null);
    else if (houseid.substring(0, 2).matches("^[DdYy]+$"))
        getDumpYardDetails(houseid);
    else {
        AUtils.warning(QRcodeScannerActivity.this, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.qr_error));
        restartPreview();
    }
}
```

Comment: From where gets the `submitQRcode` function called?

Comment: @Jonas-Within same activity

Comment: Can you maybe show me all the relevant code of this activity? Would help a lot to identify the problem.

Comment: Apply solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400680/11138845